# Is it possible to force a group member to run something allowed by sudoers as himself only?

Tags: sudo, nice

The sudoers line is

```
%game_servers   ALL=      NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/renice
```

which allows group members `renice` any process run by any user without pw, but I'd like to allow group members `renice` their own processes only, to negative value.

I couldn't spot the answer from `man sudoers`, from where I got the idea to change `ALL=(root:root)` to `ALL=`, which proved to be bad idea

`ALL=()` is syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You want group members to be able to only `renice` their own processes. This is the default behaviour without a `sudoers` entry. By default they can `renice` their own processes` nice value within the range `0 - 19`.

Having `sudo` access to `renice` allows them to increase this range from `-20 to 19` as well as `renice` processes not owned by them.

Running `man renice`, I do not see any options that will allow you to do what you want to do. If users have `sudo` access to the `renice` command, then they can add options to it that will allow them to `renice` any process.

I think that your solution is to remove the `renice` entry in the `sudoers` file. Then your users can only `renice` their own processes. They will lose the ability to set their nice values to values between `-20 and -1`, but that is the trade-off required here.

Comment: I think I should had been more verbose. Indeed, I meant negative nice.

Comment: I can't see how you would achieve that. If your users have access to `renice` in the `sudoers` file, then there is no way to prevent them from adding any process ID to the renice command that they want to.

Comment: At least not without a daemon running inside kernel looking at what's being run.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper around `renice`, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
priority="$1"
pid="$2"

owner=`ps -h -o uid $pid`
if [ $owner != ${SUDO_UID} ]; then
    echo "Only your own processes can be reniced" >&2
    exit 1
fi
renice $priority $pid
```

Note, that the example is fragile and prone to race conditions because of the delay between the ownership check and the change of the priority.